# Is the quantization aka quality factor of Pi camera images an integer or floating point value?

Tags: camera, video

I want to make small changes to the size of video files produced by a Pi camera. I have a feedback loop that frequently measures video file size, since I have short duration files, and adjusts q in real time. I've assumed q is an integer, but that limits the size of changes. Is q a floating point value so I can enter, e.g., 32.5, in the command string that I feed to raspivid ?

Comment: Why not experiment and find out?

Comment: I looked at several descriptions but none specified the data type. This is a flaw in the descriptions. I ran some tests and it appears to handle a decimal fraction, but I need to know what the developers intend it to be so I don't get stuck if they decide to change a currently unspecified data type.

Comment: We are not the developers.  Your best bet would be to ask on the Raspberry Pi Org forums.